# Angular proper way of displaying model calculated data on template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Considering a `Person` model, for example:

```
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

and a calculated/derived data from it, such as `fullName` that is `` `${firstName} ${lastName}` `` (this is just an example because the calculation could be more complex and heavy).

What is the proper way to display the calculated data on components template? Considering that:

- I want to respect DRY as much as possible, I don't want duplicate my model or write many times on templates `{{ person.firstName }} {{ person.lastName }}`;
- It is not viable to use getters or methods on template, due to performance issue, even using `OnPush` change detection strategy;
- The calculation logic must stay in the model, because I need to use it somewhere in the TS code, so I don't want to use pure pipes, or the [proposed component computed properties](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20472) (if at some time will be implemented) or some workaround to get a similar behavior.

I have considered to use an immutable approach to the `Person` model, and calculate derived properties only in the constructor:

```
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  readonly fullName: string;
  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  }
}
```

Obviously with this approach I can't do `person.firstName = 'Changed'` to also update `fullName` property, but I have to do `person = new Person('Changed', person.lastName)`.
I've considered to apply `readonly` also to `firstName` and `lastName` to ensure the immutability pattern, but in this way I'm not able to use `Person` model in another template context where, for example, I need to bind `firstName` and `lastName` to some inputs models.

I'm really interested to know what is the standard/proper/best practice way to properly handle this common situation.

Comment: Have you considered using a pure function, observables and the async pipe? Then the page can communicate to the user that page is calculating some value.

Comment: @Calidus could you provide an answer with an example use of this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider Using properties (get)

```js
class Person {
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
 
 get fullName(): string { return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;}

 constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

To optimize for often occuring changes and reduce the recalculation you can use a Subject and pipe it with debounceTime.

```js
class Person{

  private _firstName: string;
  private _lastName: string;
  private _fullName: string;
  private _debounceFirstname = new Subject<string>();
  private _debounceLastname = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._debounceFirstname
           .pipe(debounceTime(300)).subscribe((value: string) => this.firstName = value);
    this._debounceLastname
           .pipe(debounceTime(300)).subscribe((value: string) => this.lastName = value);
    this.changeCalculation();
  }

  get firstName(): string {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  set firstName(value: string) {
    this._firstName = value;
    this.changeCalculation();
  }
  get lastName(): string {
    return this._lastName;
  }

  set lastName(value: string) {
    this._lastName = value;
    this.changeCalculation();
  }

  get fullName(): string{
    return this._fullName;
  }

  private changeCalculation(): void {
      this._fullName= `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

}
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, this is not viable due to change detention performance issue.

Comment: @Hazzard17 I eddited my Answer. maybe this could help

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to avoid the getters and methods, but I am not entirely convinced that the performance downsides of such approach are so expensive. In general, if those getters and methods don't do some heavy work, I don't think you should drop them. Of course, as in your case, these operations can be more complex.

My subjective approach to handle this scenario would be to utilize getters and setters, while avoiding the `fullName` calculations as much as possible:

```
class Person {
  _firstName: string;
  _lastName: string;
  _fullName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this._fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`; // First setting of the fullName
  }

  get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  set firstName(newFirstName: string) {
    if (newFirstName !== this._firstName) {
      // Update the full name
      this._fullName = `${newFirstName} ${this._lastName}`;
      this._firstName = newFirstName;
    }
  }

  get lastName() {
    return this._lastName;
  }

  set lastName(newLastName: string) {
    if (newLastName !== this._lastName) {
      // Update the full name
      this._fullName = `${this._firstName} ${newLastName}`;
      this._lastName = newLastName;
    }
  }

  get fullName() {
    // Memoizing the full name
    if (!this._fullName) {
      // The full name is not going to be recalculated every time
      this._fullName = `${this._firstName} ${this._lastName}`;
    }
    return this._fullName;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could be a good solution to memoizing and recalculating the minimum number of times the complex property, but this way you use all getters on the template, that for me is a bad practice, and could result in performance issues with complex templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reactive-ish example. Some people think the use of BehaviorSubject is a bit of anti-pattern in RXJS, but that is a different discussion.

Template Code - Use an async pipe to get values out of an observable and to manage the subscriptions.

```
<div>{{myPerson.fullName$ | async}}</div>
```

Model Code - Define a behavior subject for first and last name. Use combinelatest to detect changes to first or last name.

```
class Person {
  private firstNameSubject: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  private lastNameSubject: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  fullName$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject(firstName);
    this.lastNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject(lastName);
    this.fullName$ = combineLatest([firstName, lastName]).pipe(
        map(([first, last]) => computeFullName(first, last)),
        shareReplay(1) //make our stream replayable to so we don't need to recompute the value per subscription
    );
  }
  setfirstName(newFirstName: string) {
    this.firstNameSubject.next(newFirstName);
  }
  setlastName(newLastName: string) {
    this.lastNameSubject.next(newLastName);
  }
  getFirstName() {
    return this.firstNameSubject.value;
  }
  getLastName() {
    return this.lastNameSubject.value;
  }

}
export function computeFullName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}
```